# ADF DVT dvt:lineChart Configuration

Tags: jakarta-ee, facelets, oracle-adf

I want to use dvt:lineChart to display 30 date string on X axis, and their corresponding cash balance on Y axis. Unfortunately, I am stuck with ADF framework.

To make label of X axis less crowded, instead of displaying all past 30 days on X axis, I want to display only every Monday, but I want to all the corresponding points show up in the graph.

Below is my lineChart implementation in facelets.

//row.FormattedDisplayDate is a string attribute of VO CashBalanceByDate1, //row.CashBalance is a Double attribute of VO CashBalanceByDate1
    "
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
     "

Attempt 1: I modify FormattedDisplayDate to include every Monday. Problem: the result line contains CashBalance only of each Monday, but I want every CashBalance of past 30 days.

Please advice me how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set x axis to TimesAxisType ="enabled", but you need to pass Dates as java.util.Date. 
I don't think this component is calendar aware, so you could start on monday, unless your collection is set in that way.